# How to serialize/deserialize Dictionary<string, int>().OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value) to Json?

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to serialize Dictionary to .json file and to deserialize it from the current file.

**I have the next code:**

```cs
string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>() {   
    { "aaa", 1},
    { "bbb", 2},
    { "ccc", 3}
};
```

**This works fine**

```cs
File.WriteAllText(filePath + "IndexedStrings.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

**The result is:**

```
{
    "aaa": 1,
    "bbb": 2,
    "ccc": 3
}
```

**But when I use this:**

```cs
File.WriteAllText(filePath + "IndexedStrings.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value), Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

**The result is:**

```
[
    {
        "Key": "ccc",
        "Value": 3
    },
    {
        "Key": "bbb",
        "Value": 2
    },
    {
        "Key": "aaa",
        "Value": 1
    }
]
```

Should I use different way to serialize the `Dictionary()` or how can I deserialize it?

Comment: Why do you care about the order of the keys?

Comment: The expectation is that you respond to comments.

Comment: To be honest, without handcrafting the serialization code here, that is, constructing the correct JObject, and then manually adding the properties, I don't think there is an easy way to do this. Again, I question *why* you need to do this. The reason I don't believe there is an easy fix is that any attempt to get Json.Net to serialize it *as a dictionary* means *it has to be a dictionary*, and dictionaries are per definition unordered. `SortedDictionary` sorts on the *keys*, so again...

Comment: The reason why I ask why you care about the ordering is that I don't see what you would be using this json for other than to deserialize it back into something like a dictionary, in which case the order would make no difference. If you just want to make it nice for a person that will edit this file, you should probably be ordering by key instead of value, though this will again get you into the exact same problem. My advice: Don't mess with ordering, serialize as-is.

Comment: Here is information about deserializing dictionary with newtonsoft: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm

Comment: After running the dictionary through OrderByDescending, it's no longer a dictionary and therefore it serializes differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, generally you shouldn't care about the order of your object properties. That's one of the fundamental differences between objects and arrays.

However, if you insist, you can manually construct a `JObject` from your pre-ordered pairs then serialize it:

```
var jObj = new JObject();

foreach (var kv in dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value))
{
    jObj.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
}

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```